# How to add test results in Azure DevOps through REST API java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've tried with program below but test results are not added in VSTS:

```
public static void addTestResults() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
     String pat = "abc@abc.com:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
     byte[] byteArray2 = Base64.encodeBase64(pat.getBytes());
     String encodedString2 = new String(byteArray2);

     HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
     HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/XXX/_apis/test/runs/1000012/results?api-version=5.0-preview.5" );
     List<NameValuePair> arguments1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
     arguments1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("state", "Completed"));
     arguments1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("testPoint", "{\"id\":40}"));
     arguments1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("outcome", "Passed"));
     arguments1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("testCase", "{\"id\":7340}"));

     try {
         postRequest.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
         patchRequest.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");
         postRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedString2);
         postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arguments1,"UTF-8"));

         HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
         System.out.println("Out is"+EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

     }    catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Following is the output:

```
Out is
{  
"$id":"1",
"innerException":null,
"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: results",
"typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib",
"typeKey":"ArgumentNullException",
"errorCode":0,
"eventId":0
}
```

Can anyone help me out where I am going wrong. I am trying to solve it for days but in vain.

Comment: Seems, that your json is not valid. You need to get correct request example and compare with final request body, which you are sending. If you can provide this example here, would be easier to find problem.

Comment: POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC/_apis/test/Runs/24/results?api-version=5.0-preview.5

Request Body:

[
  {
    "testCaseTitle": "VerifyWebsiteTheme",
    "automatedTestName": "FabrikamFiber.WebSite.TestClass.VerifyWebsiteTheme",
    "priority": 1,
    "outcome": "Passed"
  },
  {
    "testCaseTitle": "VerifyWebsiteLinks",
    "automatedTestName": "FabrikamFiber.WebSite.TestClass.VerifyWebsiteLinks",
    "priority": 2,
    "outcome": "Failed",
    "associatedBugs": [
      {
        "id": 30
      }
    ]
  }
]

Comment: This is the reference link that I used:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Comment: What about request body, which is sent in request? Can you get final request, which is being sent? You can get it using debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution and here it is:

```
public static void addTestResults() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
     String pat = "abc@abc.com:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
     byte[] byteArray2 = Base64.encodeBase64(pat.getBytes());
     String encodedString2 = new String(byteArray2);
    String reqbody = "{\n" + 
            "        \"state\": \"Completed\",\n" + 
            "        \"testPoint\": {\n" + 
            "          \"id\": 40\n" + 
            "        },\n" + 
            "        \"outcome\": \"Passed\",\n" + 
            "        \"testCase\": {\n" + 
            "          \"id\": 7390\n" + 
            "        }\n" + 
            "      }";
     HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
     HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/XXX/_apis/test/runs/1000012/results?api-version=5.0-preview.5" );


     try {
         postRequest.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
         patchRequest.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");
         postRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedString2);
         postRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(reqbody, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));

         HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
         System.out.println("Out is"+EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

     }    catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```